# How can I add a short PHP code into my PHP file

Tags: php

I have PHP file name `functions.php`, I want to insert a code like this
`$timestamp = time()`; into

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'luciferlevi', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/luciferlevi.css', array(), I WANT TO PUT THE $timestamp here , 'all' );
```

what format or syntax I would use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the variable and put it in the argument list.

```
$timestamp = time();
wp_enqueue_style( 'luciferlevi', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/luciferlevi.css', array(), $timestamp, 'all' );
```

Comment: Thank you. I though I need something like echo to print it.

Comment: Why would you need to print it? You're just using it as the version argument to the function.